# Splitting string by '#' followed by a number

Tags: python, string

I have a string like this 'galore#2 abounding#1 lost#3'. But I need to split this string like this ['galore', 'abounding', 'lost']. Basically the strings should be split by number. I am a newbie in Python programming, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'd need to use string split twice, you might be better off using a regex but you need to show what you've tried and researched yourself.

Comment: `[item.split('#')[1] for item in 'galore#2 abounding#1 lost#3'.split()]`. For learning you'll have to adjust that somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Regex. `re.findall`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = 'galore#2 abounding#1 lost#3'
print(re.findall(r"[a-z]+(?=\#)", s))
```

**Output:**

```
['galore', 'abounding', 'lost']
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you @Rakesh

Comment: Your lookahead doesn't check for the presence of a number. Also you don't need to escape the `#`, it's not a metacharacter.